# sendto: Operation not permitted: netsnmp

Tags: c, linux, snmp, net-snmp

I get an error from the net-snmp library doing an snmp get that says

```
Operation not permitted error from sendto.
```

I am wondering what could make the `sendto(2)` system call fail with this error.

Note, this is an intermittent error so I didn't think it was caused by a firewall issue, unless a firewall could cause this intermittently.

Comment: Both SElinux and SMACK provide security hooks into the `socket_sendmsg` kernel security call. Are you running with SELinux or SMACK policy that might forbid this call?

Comment: Would SElinux cause intermittent failures or would it always fail?  I am getting intermittent failures.

Comment: it might _look_ intermittent, if your policy allows sending to sockets of [some types but not others](http://lwn.net/Articles/184261/). At least, it would leave AVC messages in your `/var/log/audit/audit.log` or `/var/log/messages` or `dmesg(1)` output...

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me today, in my case the problem was due to conntrack table being full.

Additional symptom is lots of "`nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet`" in syslog. If this is the case, the solution is to set `net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max` (aka `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max`) to a higher value, for example:

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 65536
# sysctl net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max=1548576
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 1548576
```

As said by others, there could be other possible reasons for this, like SELinux or AppArmor policies. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

if the error code is EPERM, you are using privileged port as non-root user

Use ports > 1024